# Time For Another Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle

My Prefix is the chemical formula of a certain organic compound, without the numbers of course

My Infix is what you use to call a lovely lady

My Suffix, a very common word, can be found in this question

Try to find the word!

Extra Hint :

> The word consists of 9 letters

Comment: Never a time when not in the mood to solve a riley riddle

Comment: Ikr. These kind of riddles are amazingly fun! @Duck

Comment: Ethane and propane have the common ch as a prefix

Comment: Yes the prefix is CH. Have you gotten the answer yet? @Duck

Comment: What does it mean in the second line?

Comment: Well you use the infix to call a lovely lady @Duck

Comment: Ok, I guess are the answers correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it

> Chemistry

Prefix (credits to @Duck)

> CH

Infix

> mis (miss)

Suffix

> try ("Try to find the word!")

Comment: Beat me by a second, did you read the comments to help you because you have no explanation for the prefix I found

Comment: Correct answer. BTW, if you use the comments for some help, please give credit to @Duck for the prefix part

Comment: @Duck How many letters is it?

Comment: Are u sure about that? Chemistry is 9 letters long @Duck

Comment: Sorry, I thought the suffix had to be nine letters long

Comment: I was already thinking of CH at the start, but yeah the comments definitely confirmed it ;) Will edit!

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Chameleon

Prefix:

> CH is a chemical compound, credited to @Duck's comment

Infix:

> I'm not really sure, but AMELIE is woman's name (or based one the Amelie movie)

Suffix

> ON is a common word and can be found in the "questiON"

Another clue:

> Chameleon have ability to mimic its environment, so we need try to find it

Comment: Did you see the comments to help you?

Comment: My first guess rot13(gur cersvk vf PUN ohg nsgre V frr gur cnggrea sebz n srj chmmyr orsber perngrq ol BC V guvax gurer jvyy or ab bireynccvat pyhrf, naq jura V frr lbhe pbzzrag V guvax PU vf zber pbzzba)

Comment: +1 but unfortunately incorrect :(